# Maximize the sum of 3 numbers subject to 6 linear inequalities

Tags: inequality, optimization

(PUMaC 2006 Algebra #10)

If $x, y, z$ are real numbers and

\begin{alignat*}{9}2x+\ &&y+\ &&z\leq&66\\
x+\ &&2y+\ &&z\leq&60\\
x+\ &&y+\ &&2z\leq&70\\\\
x+\ &&2y+\ &&3z\leq&110\\
3x+\ &&y+\ &&2z\leq&98\\
2x+\ &&3y+\ &&z\leq&89\end{alignat*}

then what is the maximum possible value of $x+y+z$?

Attempt:
After adding together the first three equations we find $x+y+z\le 49$ and solving for equality gives us the solution $x=17$, $y=11$, $z=21$, but this breaks the 5th inequality.

It's not clear what else to do.

Comment: Is the answer $49.3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do better if we incorporate the offending inequality into the mix:
$$6(x+y+z)\le 2(x+2y+z)+(x+y+2z)+(3x+y+2z)\le2\cdot60+70+98=288\\\implies x+y+z\le 48$$
Setting equality in these three inequalities we used to compute this bound yields $(x,y,z)=(14, 12, 22)$, which satisfies the remaining inequalities and confirms $48$ is the answer.

Comment: offending inequality? do you mean objecting inequality? also, how do you know which inequalities in particular to add?

Comment: @AisforAmbition I mean the 5th inequality which doesn't hold when you solve the first three. If I have that, you can see that it's missing two 'y' and one 'z' term to make it even, so that's why I add twice the 2nd inequality (abundant 'y') and once the 3rd (abundant 'z').

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but I was just wondering: how do you know that $48$ is the absolutely lowest inequality value we can have for $x+y+z$? I understand the intuition of your reasoning, but is there a more rigorous explanation that proves why it cannot be any lower? For example, the first value you achieved was $x+y+z\leq49$, but you then showed that $x+y+z\leq48$. How do you know that you cannot "do better" than $48$?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @AisforAmbition Because $14+12+22=48$.